# Multiple recursion to iteration

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I'm learning Java and for an exercise I have to implement a recursive and an iterative method that return the following for a positive integer.

```
L(0) = 1
L(1) = 1
L(n) = L(n - 1) + L(n - 2) + 1  if  n > 1
```

The recursive method was no problem.

```
public static int rec (int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        return rec (n-1) + rec(n-2) + 1;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I can convert simple recursion to iterations and vice versa, but I don't know how to solve this one. Do you have any tips?

Edit: Thanks for the tip with the Fibonacci Sequence. I got it now:

```
public static int iter (int n) {
    int f0 = 1;
    int f1 = 1;
    int fn = 0;

    if (n > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            fn = f0 + f1 + 1;
            f0 = f1;
            f1 = fn;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
    return fn;
}
```

Comment: You are talking about the Fibonacci sequence. There are literally tons of stuff out there.

Comment: @LuisLavieri: I didn't find any problem with his question. It is a valid question and if there is many stuff out, you could post your answer. That would definitely help :)

Comment: you are asking how to do it. Please don't ask without tring. You try it and ask if you got struck with issue. SO will help you to find out the issue.

Comment: @ANjaNA: He's not asking about how to do it. He's asking to give him any tips if you have!!

Comment: Oh really?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091422/iterative-version-of-modified-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: `if (n > 1) {
        return rec (n-1) + rec(n-2) + 1;
    }`     Fibonacci is without the `+1`

Comment: @LuisLavieri: Oh, you're right, that looks like the Fibonacci sequence. I didn't recognize it from the mathematical definition. I'll look into that.

Comment: My apologies. I did not see it. Anyway, modifying the original should not be that bad.

Comment: @MWin123 For the iterative part, one thing you may want to consider looking into is called Dynamic Programming. They have a good pseudocode example of the Fibonacci sequence on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version

```
public static int modifiedFibonacci(int n)
{
   if(n > 1){
       int f1 = 0;
       int f2 = 0;
       int result = 0;
       for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
       {
          result = f1 + f2 + 2;
          f2 = f1;
          f1 = result;
       }
       return ++result;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with simply with two variable.

```
    public static int rec1(int n) {

    int result=0;
    int previous1=0;
    int previous2=0;

    int i=0;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        if(i==0 || i==1)
        {
            result=1;
        }
        else
        {
            result= previous1 + previous2 + 1;
        }

        previous2=previous1;
        previous1=result;
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you +1 for fib?

0,1,1,2,3,5,8,11 if I recall correctly, the sum of the previous 2 numbers assuming that n is greater than 1.

shouldn't it be something like:

```
int fib(int n){
if (n == 0){
       return 0;
   } else if (n == 1) {
       return 1;
   } //base case
   else{
       return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1);
   }
```

apologies if the code isn't perfect but you should get the idea.

The other answer to the iterative approach works fine, this is just to highlight the +1 with code and shouldn't be the accepted answer :)

Comment: The thing is that it is not Fibonacci. It's a modified version. But, it is easy enough to modify a working Fibonacci... Also, he was asking for an iterative solution.

Comment: @LuisLavieri, ah, my mistake.  I saw the recursive n-2 + n-1 and immediately went to that solution.